# Yii2 route using yii\rest\UrlRule with several parameters

Tags: php, rest, yii, routes, yii2

I am trying to use Yii 2 routing for REST API.

Following tutorial at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html, I have already defined (with success) a lot of rule for API entry point like so :

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
            'controller' => 'user'
        ],
    ],
]
```

Such a rule defines :

- GET /users (list users)
- GET /users/123 (show detail of user 123)

Now, my users have games. So I'd like to have urls :

- GET /users/123/games (list games of user 123)
- GET /users/123/games/864 (details of game 864 for user 123 - such as his scores)

I tried defining my new entry point (withhout success) like so:

```
'rules' => [
    ... previous rules ...,
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => [
            'game'
        ],
        'tokens' => [
            '{userid}' => '<userid:\\d>',
            '{gameid}' => '<gameid:\\d>',
        ],
        'patterns' => [
            'GET,HEAD /users/{userid}/games' => 'index',
            'GET,HEAD /users/{userid}/games/{gameid}' => 'view',
        ]
    ]
]
```

This definition seems wrong because I get a 404 Page not found error.
How should I define my new url routes ?
I would like to use an equivalent format for my definitions, extending 'yii\rest\UrlRule'

I am not sure if this is even possible, the tutorial not mentionning this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out how to use more complex rules.

First, the solution, then the explanation.

Here is the solution:

```
'rules' => [
    ... previous rules ...,
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'game',
        'prefix' => '/users/<userid:\\d+>',
        'tokens' => [
            '{gameid}' => '<gameid:\\d+>',
        ],
        'patterns' => [
            'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
            'GET,HEAD {gameid}' => 'view',
        ]
    ]
]
```

And now the explanation:

- First my userid / gameid attributes were badly defined. There was a missing "+" after "\d"
- The controller seems to be automatically added as a prefix to the patterns. So you have to define both a controller and a prefix (that will be added before the controller).
- Parameters in the prefix does not seem to be parsed to find tokens. So I wrote directly the regexp in the prefix instead of adding "userid" as a token.
- Finally, there are various "/" automatically added during concatenation of "prefix/controller/pattern" so you don't have to write one.
- Do not forget the pluralization rule too ! "game" is singular" but valid urls will be

  - /users/123/games
  - /users/123/games/789

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that and this helped me

Comment: Hi how can I add date token? I have also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117). Can you pl check it?

Answer (score 2):

I think there´s a simple solutions, please try this:

```
'rules' => [
                ...
                '/users/<userId:\\d+>/games' => 'game/index' ,
                '/users/<userId:\\d+>/games/<gameId:\\d+>' => 'game/view' ,
                ....
];
```

Comment: Hi how can I add date token? I have also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117). Can you pl check it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [yii2-nested-rest](https://github.com/tunecino/yii2-nested-rest)

It provides REST API for MANY-to-MANY relations in Yii2 framework.

Hope comments will make the magic more understandable:

```
'rules' => [
// this usual rule for base Yii2 rest usage
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['sitecomponent' ,'sitepage' , 'sitedomain'], 'pluralize'=>false
],
// then rules for yii2-nested-rest
[
    // url    sitepage/NNN/sitecomponent[/MMM]
    //       ^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //       resourceName   model-endpoint
    'class' => 'tunecino\nestedrest\UrlRule',
    'modelClass' => 'app\models\SitePage',
    'resourceName' => 'sitepage',
    'relations'   => ['components' =>          ['sitecomponent'=>'sitecomponent'] ],
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    //              relation name                url-endpoint    controller]
    //              defined in model SitePage    model-endpoint   with Actions from nested
    ],
    [
    // cross url    sitecomponent/NNN/sitepage[/MMM]
    'class' => 'tunecino\nestedrest\UrlRule',
    'modelClass' => 'app\models\SiteComponent',
    'resourceName' => 'sitecomponent',
    'relations' => ['pages'        =>          ['sitepage'  =>  'sitepage'] ],
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^
    //              relation name              url-endpoint     controller
    //              from model SiteComponent   model-endpoint   with Actions from nested
    ],
```

],

Comment: And current version of yii2-nested-rest does not work with PHP 7.2 because  generates error "Cannot use yii\\base\\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name". You should rename Object to BaseObject in "vendor/tunecino/yii2-nested-rest/src/UrlRule.php" everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

GET xx.com/v2/publication/12/p/34

```
[
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'pluralize' => false,//controller是否复数
                'controller' => 'v2/publication',//此处一定要加上v2
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\d[\\d,]*>',
                    '{phase}' => '<phase:\\d[\\d,]*>',
                ],
                // 通过extraPatterns和tokens来实现多个参数传递
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET,HEAD {id}/p/{phase}' => 'phase',
                ],
            ],
```

IN ACTION

```
public function actionPhase($id, $phase){}
```

Comment: please write in English

Comment: giving solution,not for help :)